# Kendo Angular dynamic grid creation based on drop down value selection

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid which updates based on a value from a dropdown. The number of columns/data will be completely different for each dropdown value selected.

Below is sample of response for Dropdown selected : TestTable

```
"data": [{
        "id": 91,
        "number": 12312,
        "isDeleted": false,
        "createdBy": "test user",
        "createdDate": "2023-05-16T10:47:24.7",
        "modifiedBy": "test user",
        "modifiedDate": "2023-05-16T10:51:35.75",
        "columnCount": 8
    },
    {
        "id": 90,
        "number": 83010,
        "isDeleted": false,
        "createdBy": "System",
        "createdDate": "2023-05-11T04:39:13.957",
        "modifiedBy": null,
        "modifiedDate": null,
        "columnCount": 8
    },
    {
        "id": 89,
        "number": 100794,
        "isDeleted": false,
        "createdBy": "System",
        "createdDate": "2023-05-11T04:39:02.817",
        "modifiedBy": null,
        "modifiedDate": null,
        "columnCount": 8
    }]
```

Below is response for dropdown selected : TestTable2

```
"data": [{
        "id": 913,
        "comment": "test comments,
        "isDeleted": false,
        "createdBy": "test user",
        "createdDate": "2023-05-16T10:47:24.7",
        "modifiedBy": "test user",
        
    },
    {
        "id": 909,
        "comment": "like comments",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "createdBy": "System",
        "createdDate": "2023-05-11T04:39:13.957",
        "modifiedBy": null,
    
    }]
```

when the data is bind to kendogrid, the columns names are displayed but rows are assigned with values as shown in below picture

[image]

kendo-grid-column in my template

```
     <kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let columnTitle of getColumnTitles()" [field]="columnTitle" [title]="columnTitle"
 [minResizableWidth]="100">
   <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
     <input [(ngModel)]="dataItem[columnTitle]" class="k-textbox" />
   </ng-template>
 </kendo-grid-column>
```

getCoulmnTitles() function in component file

```
      getColumnTitles(): string[] {
    if (this.masterGridData && this.masterGridData.length > 0) {
      return Object.keys(this.masterGridData[0]);
    }
    return [];
  }
```